# Serialization Exception, End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, networking, serialization, stream, deserialization

I hve this school project where I'm making a turn based RPG over a LAN, using TCPClient-Server. So far I've been able to send from both clients their selected classes to the server by serializing and deserializing the objects, but now I'm having trouble sending the Player 2 character to the Player 1 client (Player 1 acts as a host, and the server program runs in that computer).

### Client Code

```
//part where I send the character to the server
byte[] player;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(ms, Player);
player = ms.ToArray();
byte[] DLen = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)player.Length);
netstream = Cliente.GetStream();
netstream.Write(DLen, 0, 4);
netstream.Write(player, 0, player.Length);
netstream.Flush();
ms.Flush();

//part where I receive the other client's character from the server
byte[] DataLength = new byte[4];
netstream = Cliente.GetStream();
netstream.Read(DataLength, 0, 4);//<----HOST Client "skips" this line (executes instruction BEFORE Reset Event was notified in server side)
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(DataLength, 0);
player = new byte[length];
netstream.Read(player, 0, length);
ms = new MemoryStream(player);
bf = new BinaryFormatter();
ms.Position = 0;
object ob = bf.Deserialize(ms);//<----Line where exception appears ONLY on HOST Client
CPU = (ACharacter)ob;
netstream.Flush();
```

### Server Code

```
AutoResetEv.WaitOne();//<---Waits until BOTH players have selected their characters
//Begin sending to P2
byte[] player;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(ms, Player1);
player = ms.ToArray();
byte[] DataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)player.Length);
netstream = Jug2Sock.GetStream();
netstream.Write(DataLength, 0, 4);
netstream.Write(player, 0, player.Length);
netstream.Flush();
//Finished sending to P2

//Begin sending to P1
ms = new MemoryStream();
bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(ms, Player2);
player = ms.ToArray();
DataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)player.Length);
netstream = Jug1Sock.GetStream();
netstream.Write(DataLength, 0, 4);
netstream.Write(player, 0, player.Length);
netstream.Flush();
//Finished sending to P1
```

I don't really know what's the issue here, as Player 1's character is sent properly to Player 2 with the same code, however I noticed that for some reason, in P1's Client the line to read the data length is "skipped". With that I mean saying that Client 1 just executes the instruction before the server sends the data (server was put on hold by AutoResetEvent in order to control it).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `netstream.Read(player, 0, length);` You have to check here how many bytes are actually read. For example `int bytesRead = netstream.Read(player, 0, length);` It is not guaranteed that it is 4.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, first I send the size of the data I want to read: netstream.Read(DataLength, 0, 4); I send that data first and I know it is 4 bytes, as it was specified as that, then I use the length to deserialize the other part, thing is it seems the data isn't being sent correctly by some reason

Comment: The problem is `netstream.Read(...)`. If you code: `int y = netstream.Read(DataLength, 0, x);` then y can be any number between 0 and x. That is the point what you need to handle.

Comment: The funny thing is that the data is incorrect in the Client of the host computer only, so I think the issue might be other thing, as I said before Client 1 "skips" the read line, not literally, it does it, but it's a line that should be exectued ONLY AFTER Client 2 chose a character, but it executes the line BEFORE it happens, however if Client 2 makes a choice before Client 1, Client 2 doesn't get the exception, but Client 1 gets it anyway

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to handle the number of bytes read that is returned by the Read operation

```
        netstream = Cliente.GetStream();            
        int numBytesToRead = 4;
        do
        {
            // Read may return anything from 0 to 4. 
            int n = netstream.Read(DataLength, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        } while (numBytesToRead > 0);
        int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(DataLength, 0);
```

This is an example how to handle the reading of the first 4 bytes (which contains DataLength). Reading player data could be done like this:

```
        player = new byte[length];
        numBytesRead = 0;
        numBytesToRead = length;
        do
        {            
            int n = netstream.Read(player, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;
        } while (numBytesToRead > 0);        
        ms = new MemoryStream(player);
```

Comment: I agree. But it can be helpful to find out if have no byte count mismatches or network problems. Therefore, I wrote that it is a starting point, and is not the best solution. Certainly, more work has to be done. And also, I wanted to point out where the check on number of bytes read has to be added.

Comment: I agree that it not correct to post code that might result to bad coding practices. I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. :) It is probably the best answer that can be provided until the OP provides a better question, assuming you fix the typo: `int numBytesRead = 4;` should probably be `int numBytesToRead = 4;`

Comment: Not any more; was part of the fix.

Comment: I don't think that's it, as the problem is not reading the data incorrectly, but it just reads it in a moment it shouldn't, maybe the problem wasn't that clear so I'll update the question, and anyway I'll try doing what you say, so thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes, it was even correct when I saw it. The loop is just written in a style I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Your code gives me the same result as mine, In length in client 2 I got 1521 and deserialized the object correctly, however in client 1 the length was 1 and got the exception, I had already checked that without your code and I got the same results, I suppose it has more to do with what I'm receiving from the server than anything else, thank you anyway.

Comment: If you want to know what you get from the server, you could try a network sniffer like WireShark. Not easy stuff for a beginner (not sure you are - just making the note also for other readers), but sooner or later when you are more involved in network programming it's very helpful. And it is free. https://www.wireshark.org/